# How to shape set of divs in a pyramid shape like a tree?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

If I have the following HTML structure:

```
 <div class="slots-container">
            <div class="slot"></div>
            <div class="slot"></div>
            <div class="slot"></div>
            <div class="slot"></div>
            <div class="slot"></div>
            <div class="slot"></div>
</div>
```

---

The following CSS:

```
 <style>
  .slots-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            grid-gap: 5px;
        } 


        .slot {
            border: 2px dashed #ccc;
            padding: 5px;
            min-height: 300px;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

            .slot:nth-child(3) {
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #e66465, #9198e5);
            }

            .slot:nth-child(2),
            .slot:nth-child(1) {
                background: linear-gradient(to top left, #EAEAEA, #C4C4C4);
            }

            .slot:nth-child(4),
            .slot:nth-child(5),
            .slot:nth-child(6) {
                background: linear-gradient(to top left, #D9D9D9, #ADADAD);
            }


            .slot:hover {
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
            }

            .slot::before {
                content: "Drop Expert Card Here";
                position: absolute;
                top: 1px;
                left: 1px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 40px;
                background-color: #ffd700;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: bold;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                font-family: inherit;
                color: black;
                border-bottom: 1px;
                border-color: dimgrey;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
            }

            .slot:nth-child(3)::before {
                content: "خبير صناعة فئة-أ";
                background-color: #ffd700;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .slot:nth-child(2)::before,
            .slot:nth-child(1)::before {
                content: "خبير صناعة فئة-ب";
                background-color: #c0c0c0;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .slot:nth-child(4)::before,
            .slot:nth-child(5)::before,
            .slot:nth-child(6)::before {
                content: "خبير صناعة فئة-ج";
                background-color: #cd7f32;
                text-align: center;
            }


        #temp_emp {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            min-height: 280px;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            border: 2px dashed #ccc;
        }

        .placeholder1 {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 2px dashed #999;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }

        .placeholder-text {
            color: #999;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .arrow-icon {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: #999;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .placeholder1:hover {
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }

        .placeholder1:before {
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            color: #888;
            opacity: 0.6;
        }


        .temp-emp-card {
            width: 250px;
            height: 250px;
            border: 2px solid #999;
            margin: 5px;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        .card {
            background-color: #f8f8f8;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            padding: 1px;
            text-align: center;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        }

            .card:hover {
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
            }

        .emp-photo {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

            .emp-photo img {
                width: 130px;
                height: 130px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                object-fit: cover;
                border: 4px solid #fff;
                box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            }

        .card-title {
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            padding: 8px 16px;
            background-color: #e2e2e2;
            color: #333;
            border-radius: 20px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .card-text {
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #888;
        }

        .delete-button {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            right: 5px;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            color: #dc3545;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .details-button {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            left: 5px;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            color: #dc3545;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .card-body {
            padding: 1px;
        }
    </style>
```

---

According to @Rene Answer :

```
 <style>
 .slots-container {
    display: grid;
    gap: 0.3125rem;
    grid-template-areas: ". . a a . ."
        ". b b c c ."
        "d d e e f f";
    margin: 1px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slot:nth-child(1) {
    grid-area: b
}

.slot:nth-child(2) {
    grid-area: c
}

.slot:nth-child(3) {
    grid-area: a
}

.slot:nth-child(4) {
    grid-area: d
}

.slot:nth-child(5) {
    grid-area: e
}

.slot:nth-child(6) {
    grid-area: f
}

/* eye-candy only */
.slot {
    min-height: 15.2rem;
    background-color: Silver;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    font-size: 3vw;
    padding: 5px 1px 5px 1px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 370px;//The problem
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 15.2rem;
}


    .slot:nth-child(3) {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #b6d7a8, #ffd3b6);
    }

    .slot:nth-child(2),
    .slot:nth-child(1) {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #c7b8e1, #ffe0e0);
    }

    .slot:nth-child(4),
    .slot:nth-child(5),
    .slot:nth-child(6) {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #a8cbd4, #ffe6b6);
    }
    </style>
```

---

I want the slots like apyramid shape like this, How to do that maintaining the same HTML:

```
                                slot:nth-child(3)
                       slot:nth-child(1)   slot:nth-child(2)
              slot:nth-child(4)   slot:nth-child(5) slot:nth-child(6)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67267124/8620333

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61613007/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Can we do it using css grid

Comment: a pyramid is not a grid

Comment: @TemaniAfif I try your css and editing my css but it looks not like a pyramid at all, I edit my question posting my whole css

Comment: @ TemaniAfif  I donot know how to control the slot width and height, I want the large enough to drag and drop cards in, they are so small to this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a triangular `grid-template-areas` in your `slots-container` and assign the relevant `grid-area` to a specific `.slot`:

**updated** code to *`justify-content: center`* grid items...

```css
.slots-container {
    display: grid; 

    justify-content: center; /* centers grid items */
    
    gap: 5px;

    grid-template-areas: ". . a a . ."
                         ". b b c c ."
                         "d d e e f f";
}

.slot:nth-child(1) { grid-area: b }
.slot:nth-child(2) { grid-area: c }
.slot:nth-child(3) { grid-area: a }
.slot:nth-child(4) { grid-area: d }
.slot:nth-child(5) { grid-area: e }
.slot:nth-child(6) { grid-area: f }

/* eye-candy only */
.slot {
    min-height: 18rem;

    width: 10rem; /* to test justification */

    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: Silver;
    display: grid; place-items: center;
    font-size: 3vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="slots-container">
    <div class="slot">1</div>
    <div class="slot">2</div>
    <div class="slot">3</div>
    <div class="slot">4</div>
    <div class="slot">5</div>
    <div class="slot">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare I initially wanted to show you [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/poZYVqv) I created, but it didn't seem to fit your needs...

Comment: your work is great but could I ask how to edit your snippet to change the width of the slots, when i make it small the gaps become too large !, I want to keep the gaps as it's with this change

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare I changed the gap to your original `gap: 5px`

Comment: Still the same problem, I edit my code to illustrate the problem, the problem here width: 370px; when I change it to small number the gap between the slots become too large

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare  you will have to explain what you mean with 'too large' as this is not part of the issue you posted. Your original code with `gap: 5px` is equal to `gap: 0.3125rem` (being `5px/16 = 0.3125rem`, with default browser font size anyway). Don't add new issues through comments. This is unwanted on SO and leads to confusion. You also shouldn't correct your (faulty) issue code. Now readers have no clue what the issue was and cannot compare and learn from the suggested changes made in the answers...

Comment: I'm sorry, for editing on the same code set :(
What i meant : When I decrease the size of the slots, the gap between them become larger

Comment: I re-edit and rewrite my old css.

Answer (score 2):

you began to use grid, why not using positioning of each element

```css
.slots-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slot {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slot:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 7;
  background-color: rgba(163, 34, 173, 0.5);
}

.slot:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: 2 / 7 / 3 / 11;
  background-color: rgba(30, 203, 81, 0.5);
}

.slot:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: 1 / 5 / 2 / 9;
  background-color: rgba(58, 215, 181, 0.5);
}

.slot:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 5;
  background-color: rgba(178, 166, 72, 0.5);
}

.slot:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: 3 / 5 / 4 / 9;
  background-color: rgba(103, 177, 182, 0.5);
}

.slot:nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: 3 / 9 / 4 / 13;
  background-color: rgba(122, 201, 176, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="slots-container">
  <div class="slot">1</div>
  <div class="slot">2</div>
  <div class="slot">3</div>
  <div class="slot">4</div>
  <div class="slot">5</div>
  <div class="slot">6</div>
</div>
```